# Formulate residual for Levenberg-Marquart

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, least-squares, levenberg-marquardt

I want to minimize a cost function with the form,

[image: cost]

with the Levenberg-Marquart method with the scipy.optimize.least_squares function. But I do not see how to formulate it in terms of residuals, so that I can use such method. Otherwise I get the error message "Method 'lm' doesn't work when the number of residuals is less than the number of variables."

My cost function is defined as follows:

```
def canonical_cost(qv, t, A, B, C, delta, epsilon, lam):
    assert(type(qv) is np.ndarray and len(qv) == 4)
    # assert(type(t) is np.ndarray and len(t) == 3)

    q = Quaternion(*qv)
    qv, tv = qv.reshape(-1, 1), np.vstack(([0], t.reshape(-1, 1)))

    f1 = qv.T @ (A + B) @ qv
    f2 = tv.T @ C @ tv + delta @ tv + epsilon @ (q.Q.T @ q.W) @ tv
    qnorm = (1 - qv.T @ qv)**2
    return np.squeeze(f1 + f2 + lam*qnorm)
```

And I try to optimize with,

```
def cost(x):
    qv, t = x[:4], x[4:]
    return canonical_cost(qv, t, A, B, C, delta, epsilon, lam)

result = opt.least_squares(cost, initial_conditions, method='lm',
                               **kwargs)
```

Thank you

Comment: You'd have to subtract the calculated value from the actual values (f(x) - y), then square that subtraction, and return that as your cost function. I don't see you do that anywhere. In fact, I don't see your `y_i` values anywhere.

Comment: Perhaps you're better off with `curve_fit`: you can feed that the measured/actual values and the cost function directly.

Comment: yes, that is exactly my problem. I do not know what the actual values are. My problem is that I do not see if it is possible to formulate the above problem as a regression problem, so that I can use the LM method

Comment: You can't perform regression if you don't have any actual, measured values. Are you simply trying to minimize/maximize a function?

Comment: Exactly. That is what I am trying to do. In the literature this problem it is also solved with the LM method. But I do not see how they were able to. I would like to compare it to other methods like TRF or BFGS

Comment: I'm not sure if it is due to the scipy API to LM or the algorithm itself, but your type of problem is not easily solved with `scipy`'s LM method. I think you are better of sticking to `scipy.optimize.minimize`, because you are starting from the function that needs to be minimized, whereas `curve_fit` etc need to be fed with residuals so it can build the chi2 to be minimized itself.

If you really want to use LM, you are going to have to build a function whose chi2 is your function above.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, the LM algorithm performs sum of squares of the residual vector and tries to minimize that value. We need to return a vector accordingly so that the sum of squares of the elements in that vector is minimized. And the requirement of the size of this residual vector being more than the number of variables makes sense because it basically implies that number of unkno